# Error creating Coded UI Test in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, coded-ui-tests

I am attempting to create a Coded UI Test in a Visual Studio 2010 test project.
I right click on the project, 
     Select Add
        Select Coded UI Test

I then get the error warning:

> The following package failed to load:
>   C:\Users[File Path Goes
>   Here]\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.IE.dll.
>   Coded UI Test is now in an
>   inconsistent state.  Remove this
>   package and restart Visual Studio to
>   work with Coded UI Test.

Once I click OK, I can create the Coded UI Test (CUIT) but when the test is over, the test file is empty.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?  I've already deleted my settings, AND reinstalled VS 2010, all to no avail.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: It sounds to me like perhaps your UI Test module got corrupted? You might consider uninstalling it, closing VS, deleting all the cache (from your AppSettings as well), the re-installing.

Comment: I have reinstalled, as well as done a repair install.  I have not deleted the cache though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I'm prepared to declare this a massive bug on Microsoft's part, and closing it out.

Comment: And if you don't have MVC 3 scaffolding installed, everything goes smoothly?

Comment: If yes, you could add this workaround to the question to clarify what to do with it.

Comment: Uninstalling the mvc scaffolding NuGet package really does fix the problem, that's all it takes.  It makes absolutely no sense, but that's all it takes.

Answer (score 3):

No idea about the source of the problem, but if you go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\ and copy the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.IE.dll file into the bin/debug directory everything works fine.

I don't know why VS assumes that the .dll is there when it's not, but that is the fix.

Comment: I now find that the above solution only works once.  Does anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: Is that dll referenced from the project?

Comment: If yes, try removing the reference. Also, do you have any other Visual Studio installs to tests that?

Comment: And, well, is that problem reproduced when you create a project from scratch?

Comment: I have removed the reference, and I still get the same error - I have also created several projects from scratch and I still get the same error.

Comment: Weird, huh. Seems to be an environmental problem. Do you have Visual Studio Feature Pack 2?

Comment: If you post a non-working test solution somewhere, I can open it with my Visual Studio and look if it works. I'm really curious now what's wrong with it.

Comment: Here is a test solution where I get the same error.  I've even gone so far as to download the microsoft test manager, and apply every hotfixknown to man, all to no avail.  I would be hugely appreciative if you could help me with this.

Comment: It would help if I included the link  http://www.digitaltoolfactory.net/cuittest.zip

Comment: got that. In VS Premium at workplace worked fine. In 7-8 hours I'll check that under VS Ultimate at home.

Comment: Thank you.  I've been pulling my hair out over this, it would be the perfect solution for one client and I can't get it to work.

Comment: Steve, I'm really sorry to say that, but with none of my Visual Studios installed I can reproduce your issue. You seem to have some problem with OS, or CLR, or I don't even know. Were I you, I'd set up a virtual machine, put Visual Studio there and then worked. I believe that VS will work fine there. VMs are really fast to create, so it shouldn't be a big deal to create one.

Comment: That is an odd thing.  I just tried in on my home machien as well actually and I get the same error.  I woner if there is a software conflict of some kind.

Comment: Really odd. Which Windows version do you use?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 Ultimate, all patched and updated in both cases.

Comment: I'm on Enterprise and Ultimate, both x32. No more ideas what can be wrong with it. Clean install seems to be the only option to work that out.

Comment: I've done that, all to no avail, which makes me wonder what sort of conclicts I might have.  There was something about it conflicting with mvc 3 scaffolding, but I have no idea why that would be the case.

Comment: So, I'm prepared to declare this a massive bug on Microsoft's part, and closing it out.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get past this issue by changing the 'Copy Local' property of the referenced DLL to 'true'.  After this change the DLL is automatically copied into the Bin\Debug directory.