# How can I fix the conflict between Coded UI Test and MVC Scaffolding in Visual Studio 2012 RC

Tags: visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I'm running Visual Studio 2012 RC (all the latest updates have been installed as of 7/11/2012.  I have an asp.net mvc 4 solution with

1. a Web Project
2. a Unit Test Project
3. a Coded UI Test Project
4. a Web performance and load Test project

When I first created the solution I could add Coded UI Tests with no problem.  However, today I tried to create a Coded UI Test and got the following error

> The following package failed to load: C:\Users[File Path Goes
>   Here]\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll. Coded UI Test is
>   now in an inconsistent state. Remove this package and restart Visual
>   Studio to work with Coded UI Test.

I had a [similar problem before with Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630209/error-creating-coded-ui-test-in-visual-studio-2010-ultimate).  I still have that problem for that matter.

However, if I uninstall (via NuGet) MVC Scaffolding and T4Scaffolding and restart Visual Studio I can create Coded UI Tests again, but if I add back in the scaffolding packages and restart Visual Studio I get the error again and cannot create the Coded UI test.

It seems that

1. there is a conflict between the scaffolding packages and Coded UI Tests in Visual Studio
2. The original error Visual Studio 2010 error has not been fixed in Visual Studio 2012 - [Microsoft has acknowledged that this is a bug](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ta/vsautotest/thread/144b9a55-af5a-4e89-8383-d4b07817ff0f).

Can anyone help this fan of scaffolding and Coded UI Tests?  It would be great to use both technologies without workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution to this.  The only real workaround is not to use MVC Scaffolding.

Comment: I have this same problem. I'm not using Scaffolding. If I start a new, empty project I still get the error :s